# smart gwt save list as attribute

Tags: smartgwt

Hello i am new in smart gwt and now we are migrate from smartgwt 2.1 to smart gwt 3.1p
and i have got problem :

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not convert element 0 of
>   the array to a JavaScriptObject.  Instances of class
>   `com.test.ListDTO'
>   can not automatically be converted.  Please see the SmartClient
>   documentation of RPCRequest.data for a table of Java types that can be
>   converted automatically.

someone write :

```
treeNode.setAttribute(TODO, listDTO.getLis());
```

how i can fix that code ?

Answer (score 0):

The setAttribute method of the TreeNode tries to convert the list elements internally. That fails with your own domain objects. You can try to set the list with this helper method:

```
com.smartgwt.client.util.JSOHelper.setObjectAttribute(treeNode.getJsObj(), TODO, listDTO.getLis());
```

Now the Java object is set on the JavaScriptObject. To get this object back you can call:

```
treeNode.getAttributeAsObject(TODO);
```